# File not found exception when uploading a multipart file spring boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I am trying to use spring multipart to upload a file to s3 bucket. but i am getting file not found exception. When a logged file path its showing ~/project/filename. But still its throwing file not found exception when trying to upload this file to s3.

here is code -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/items/images", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadImages(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

    if (file != null) {
        File imageFile = multipartToFile(file);
        s3Uploader.s3PutImage(imageFile);
    }
}

public static File multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    File convFile = new File(multipart.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll(" ", "_"));
    multipart.transferTo(convFile);
    return convFile;
}

public void s3PutImage(File file) {

    try {
        s3.setRegion(usWest2);
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("voiceas",
                 file.getName(), file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(LOGGER_PREFIX + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Anything I am doing wrongly here.

Comment: are you sure that the file parameter recieved is not null ?

Comment: check the file path and do you see the file being uploaded to the path?